# Fix a domain error: Forced the HTTPS but placed a wrong domain now it is not changing

Tags: http, domain, https

I forced my site domain to have `https`, I used this code and added to the `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domains.co/$1 [R=301,L]
```

along with the this code, there are also code above that code which is

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Options +FollowSymLinks
# RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domains.co[nc]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://ww/w.domains.co/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

But as you can see on the first code I added and I used `http/s://domains.co/$1` rather than the right domain `domain.com`, when I run the site it causes error as it uses the wrong domain.

After that I tried to change the domain to the right one which is `domain.com` but it is not changing.

every time I access domain.com it always direct to domains.co

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue recently and for me waiting a couple of hours solved it, probably because of the browser [caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s) the redirect 301.

Try clearing the cache.
open your DevTools (press F12)
on the Network tab check the "Disable cache" checkbox
keep DevTools open and reload the page (press F5)